# Run PowerShell command using CMD over SSH

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, cmd, command-line

I run the following **PowerShell** command using **Command Prompt (CMD)** on Windows Server 2019 and it works correctly:

```
powershell -command "Get-Childitem -Path [my source path] -Include *.bak -File -Recurse | Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First 1 | Compress-Archive -Force -DestinationPath [my target path].zip"
```

But when I want to run it over **SSH**:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null [username]@[server] powershell -command "Get-Childitem -Path [my source path] -Include *.bak -File -Recurse | Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First 1 | Compress-Archive -Force -DestinationPath [my target path].zip"
```

I get error:

> 'Sort-Object' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Comment: Why not use PowerShell remoting over SSH? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: Have you tried escaping the VERTICAL LINE (pipe) characters in the command? `^|`

Comment: @lit Lots of thanks. `^|` solved my problem, but as you said PowerShell remoting is a better choice.

Comment: Just run "powershell.exe" on cmd connect ssh success, so you can run any your script with powershell.